# create dataset based on all possible pairs of identifiers within each group in Stata

Tags: stata

I have a dataset that looks like this:

| country1 | country2 | group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| China | Philippines | 68a |
| China | Thailand | 68a |
| Bahamas | Jamaica | 176a |
| Bahamas | Grenada | 176a |

I need to transform the above dataset into like this:

| country1 | country2 | group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| China | Philippines | 68a |
| China | Thailand | 68a |
| Philippines | China | 68a |
| Philippines | Thailand | 68a |
| Thailand | China | 68a |
| Thailand | Philippines | 68a |
| Bahamas | Jamaica | 176a |
| Bahamas | Grenada | 176a |
| Jamaica | Bahamas | 176a |
| Jamaica | Grenada | 176a |
| Grenada | Bahamas | 176a |
| Grenada | Jamaica | 176a |

I tried my best to follow the Stata code in this article: https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/expanding-datasets-to-all-pairs/. However, I ended up with a dataset that looks like this:

| country1 | country2 | group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| China | Philippines | 68a |
| China | Philippines | 68a |
| China | Thailand | 68a |
| China | Thailand | 68a |
| Bahamas | Jamaica | 176a |
| Bahamas | Jamaica | 176a |
| Bahamas | Grenada | 176a |
| Bahamas | Grenada | 176a |

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is because your unique identifier is really the combination of two columns (`country1` and `country2`) whereas in the example you are following there is a unique `id` column. Here is how I would do this with your example, provided your dataset isn't incredibly large:

```
clear
input str40(country1 country2 group)
"China" "Philippines"   "68a"
"China" "Thailand"  "68a"
"Bahamas"   "Jamaica"   "176a"
"Bahamas"   "Grenada"   "176a"
end

egen pair_id = group(country1 country2) // Create unique pair id
reshape long country, i(group pair_id) j(j ) // reshape all countries long
drop pair_id j
rename country country1

* create duplicate dataset to fulljoin
preserve
    rename country country2
    keep country2 group
    tempfile cross
    save `cross', replace
restore

joinby group using `cross' // full join
drop if country1 == country2

* Some tidying to match example output
order country1 country2 group
gsort -group country1 country2
duplicates drop
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to generate my desired dataset with my codes below but I'm hoping to find a more straightforward way to code it.

```
use "original dataset", clear
drop country2
save "temp_country1", replace

use "original dataset", clear
drop country1
ren country2 country1 
append using "temp_country1"

//drop duplicates//
sort number country1
quietly by number country1:  gen dup = cond(_N==1,0,_n)
drop if dup>1
drop dup
save "temp_country1_final", replace

use "temp_country1_final", clear
ren country1 country2
save "temp_country2.dta", replace

use "temp_country1_final", clear
joinby number using "temp_country2.dta"
order country1 country2  number name
drop if country1==country2
```

Comment: The last command `drop if country1=="country2"` looks quite wrong to me. The double quotes make no sense and the purpose clearly calls for `drop if country1 == country2`. That's trivial but what else are you editing casually? More importantly, @JR96 has already posted a solution, so a good answer would compare yours with theirs with some commentary.